# Are the outlets set when self.isViewLoaded returns true?

Tags: ios

I have a property that I want to use a property observer on. This property is set using segues. I want to avoid the property observer being triggered when the outlets are not set yet. I noticed self having a property named isViewLoaded. When this property returns true does this also necessarily imply the outlets were set? This is true for viewDidLoad() but is it also true for the property isViewLoaded?

```
var property: Property? {
        didSet {
            if self.isViewLoaded {updateUI()}
        }
    }
```

Comment: If the property is set once during the segue the property observer is pointless because `isViewLoaded` is always `false` at this point. Call `updateUI` in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: True when there were only 1 segue. The property is also changed using protocols after other segues in the navigation controller which are popped.

Comment: If you want to be sure, why not simply check if the relevant outlet is nil or not?

Comment: These protocols are setting like ten variables on the property. Instead of using all those nil checkings it seems cleaner to just check if the view is loaded. Hence the question.

Comment: @user3398985 You only need to check one outlet. They will either all be nil or none will be nil.

Comment: That only adds confusion. Then you ought to check all of them for nil.